# drupal form api file upload

Tags: forms, drupal, file-upload

I have a form with file attachment. Once i load the file and submit the form, if validation errors occur the form is loaded again, but the file i had uploaded is not rendered and I have to load it again.

I tried using file_save_upload but it doesnot seem to work.

```
$file_attach_set= file_save_upload('file_attachment1', array());
     //$file_attach_setII = $form_state['values']['attc'];
    $contextid = 150;

    if(empty($file_attach_setII)){
    $form['file_attachment' . $i] = array(
      '#type' => 'file',
      "#title" =>'kik'
      '#default_value'=> $file_attach_set->fid,
      //'#title_display' => $file_attach_set->uri,
      ''
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `file` element doesn't have a `#default_value` property. Try using the `managed_file` type which has this property.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#file

```
$form['file_attachment' . $i] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' =>'kik',
    '#default_value'=> array(
        'fid' => $file_attach_set->fid,
    ),
);
```